# Is it important to speak the language of your clan in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I just started Clash of Clans recently, and am around a 1000 trophy count.  I kept getting immediately kicked out of clans I joined when I was at a lower count (400-500 maybe), but finally was allowed to stay in one.

I've been in it for 3 weeks, and they only speak Indonesian.  I only speak English.  I didn't notice the clan location field...

Part of me wants to stay because the clan is functional, and they helped me out.

But part of me thinks I may need to be able to communicate with them.

How important is communicating in Clash of Clans?  Is it just giving troops back and forth, or in practice, is there often coordination on who attacks who, etc?

PS I tried a few translation sites, and it comes out as English words, but isn't comprehensible.

Comment: It really depends on what type of clan you are in.... If you are in an active war clan, it may be important to be able to communicate. However, if your clan is more laid-back, it is only necessary for troop donations.

Answer (score 3):

If someone in your clan asks for "Level 5 Hogs" in a language you don't understand you wont be able to help them and you may give them what they DO NOT want.  In war it is very important to give the troops asked for because war strategies are chosen in advance. Giving the wrong troop results in additional troop request delays.

In our clan we not only require English, but that the player names also be in the Latin alphabet.  I cannot read or write in Mandarin, so how would I address or communicate to a player with Chinese characters in his name?

Finally, for a war clan, it's not ***just language*** that matters... being in a similar timezone is very helpful.  If you are asleep while the rest of your clan is planning and attacking and v.v. you will not be much help or receive much help.

Answer (score 2):

It may seem harsh to say yes you have to speak a common language with your clan mates, but that is what I would recommend. Why, because later on when things like strategy become more important you need to be able to communicate with each other. At an early town hall level strategy is pretty much straight forward. When you get to town hall 8 you start having to think a little bit more about your strategy especially in Clan wars.

With regard to you being kicked out, make sure you are in a clan where most of the people in it are around your town hall level. This makes sure you are on common grounds and that the troops you donate to them mean something. A few higher level mates would be perfect. If you are a town hall 4 in a clan with only town hall 9s and 10s, you can imagine that they won't appreciate low level donations much. Some clans are willing to nurture beginners, usually if they show determination by for example maxing everything before moving onto the next town hall and also by showing thought out attack strategies e.t.c.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to speak the same language which they are speaking but if it is like that then you must leave that clan and join others where English is used..

You can check this thing from clan's info(clan's location, language if described in info etc) or else in global ask if is there any English speaking clan and i am sure you will find too many clan who speak English.

The reason behind kicking player from different language is they are not able to ask troupe or to give you any commend/order so they felt it like you are the **MAIN REASON** of loosing as you did not follow their plan but your fault is you just can't understand those commands..so its better to join clan who use English to communicate..